# date format conversion in R/getting NA

Tags: r, date

I am working with below lines:

```
date<-20221101
test_date<-as.Date("date","%Y%m%d")
```

Thought I would be getting 2022-11-01, but it returns with NA. While the below line returns with 2022-11-01, may I know if I would like to do it with "date", instead of "20221101", what should I do about it? Many thanks.

```
 test_date<-as.Date("20221101","%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: `as.Date(as.character(date), format="%Y%m%d")`

Comment: You are trying to convert the literal string `"date"` into a date, not the object _date_.